# Evaluation maths expressions in JavaScript strings

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have two text boxes on my Form. One is `txtNumberOfTablets` and the other one is `txtTotalQuantity`.

I have a HiddenField and I am setting its value in code behind file on page load.

`hdfMedicationDosage = "2/3/4";`

What I want is, whatever user enters to `txtNumberOfTablets` textbox, should be multiplied with `hdfMedicationDosage` value when focus is out of `txtNumberOfTablets`.

For example `txtNumberOfTablets` contains value 2, and focus is out of `txtNumberOfTablets`, then that `txtTotalQuantity` will have a value `2*2/3*2/4*2` i.e.`4/6/8`

I want to achieve this in JavaScript.

Comment: How much dollars, you will pay us for this assignment ? :) You should provide your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: LOL I haven't tried anything yet because I have a lot work to do :( I'll try soon and then will edit my question.

Comment: You can share some work with us, so your burden will be less :)

Comment: For that, I will have to give a longggg description for you to get the domain understanding :-s

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function that takes the string value in `hdfMedicationDosage` and uses the [string.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method to get an array of the numbers as strings. Then just iterate through the array and convert each string using [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) before doing each multiplication. You can then concatenate the values back together as strings to populate `txtTotalQuantity`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/f3TGV/) for a way to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var theValue = "2/3/4", multiplier = '2', newArray=[], valArray;

    valArray = theValue.split('/');

    for(var i=0;i<valArray.length;i++){
        newArray.push(valArray[i] * multiplier);
    }

    var newValue = newArray.join('/');

    $("#result").text(newValue);
});
```